# Получение информации с xml C#

Tags: c#, xml

Есть [страничка](http://xml.weather.co.ua/1.2/forecast/23?dayf=5). Мне нужно с этой странички взять `city id=" " и t /t`. Как это реализовать на c#?

Comment: Простой XPath запрос не устраивает?

Comment: Чтение данных из файла http://habrahabr.ru/post/24673/

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример кода:

```
var xmlPath = @"http://xml.weather.co.ua/1.2/forecast/23?dayf=5";
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var city = doc.Descendants("city").First().Element("name").Value;
var currentTemp = doc.Root.Element("current").Element("t").Value;
Console.Write("Current temp in city {0} = {1}\r\n",city, currentTemp);
```